# joining tables with different number of entries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins, table

I work in ArcGIS 10.3 and I have this problem:

I have a dbf table of about 300 restaurants, each restaurant has a different values like address, number of seats etc.
I have another dbf table of beers that are tapped in the above mentioned restaurants. For each record of a restaurant in the first table, there are one or many records in the second table, for example:

**Table 1**

```
Restaurant "A", Elm Street 15
Restaurant "B", Ash Road 4
```

**Table 2**

```
Restaurant "A", Elm Street 15, Beer_type1, Beer_type1_price 
Restaurant "A", Elm Street 15, Beer_type2, Beer_type2_price 
Restaurant "A", Elm Street 15, Beer_type3, Beer_type3_price  
Restaurant "B", Ash Road 4,    Beer_type2, Beer_type2_price    
Restaurant "B", Ash Road 4,    Beer_type3, Beer_type3_price
```

I'm trying to join (or relate?) the 2nd table to the 1st one, so I could see  (hopefully in a single row) which beers are available in which restaurant. It would be something as "join one to many". I researched some but didn't find a suitable solution. I found very useful tool called "Add Relate" which is available only in ArcGIS Pro, so that's not an option.
When done, I will add points (X,Y coords) of the restaurant to the map and each point should have attributes of the 1st table AND of the 2nd. Any tips how to handle this?

Comment: Adding a relate is available in ArcGIS desktop using a relationship class (one to many), the question is what are you trying to achieve in the end? How will you be digesting the data? Relates can be a little tricky to work with... perhaps you can compile table 2  into a single line per entry by adding more beer type fields then use a standard join.

Comment: You have a many to many (M-M) situation, but for purposes of your map, you can probably treat it as a 1-M, since you only need the address once per restaurant to place the point.    Try this link as a start: https://community.esri.com/message/612348?commentID=612348#comment-612348

Comment: you can do it using vlookup excel function to put all the diferents beers for each restaurant, after that you can use the information to mapping all, can you share the field of your tables? to see what you got

Comment: There are 26 fields for the restaurants, don't know if it helps to copy them here...And 4 fields for the beers. I thought about vlookup but I don't think it could solve my problem...

Comment: @Michael Stimson: I thought about it too, but it would prove troublesome because I need to do further analysis like having one beer brand under the same column so I could calculate average price etc. etc. I have about 55 different brands of beer (each brand coming with different types too - like lager, stout etc) so the table would have over hundred fields...

Comment: The list of restaurants and the list of beers are connected by ID (like in the example I made in the original post).